# CDB load .pdb file at offset

Tags: debugging, windbg, pdb-files

I am trying to load a symbol file at a specific offset in memory in CDB.
Something just like the command for GDB:

```
gdb add-symbol-file address
```

Is there any way to do this? I have tried making a WinDBG plugin, but can not find any helpful functions.

Comment: I'm not sure what this should mean. I always thought that the symbols are loaded into the address space of WinDbg. Why would you want to control the memory layout of the WinDbg process? To me, this looks like a XY issue. What are you really trying to achieve with those symbols?

Comment: i forgot to mention that i am working on dump files. I do not debug an application, i need to extract as much information as I can from a dump.

Comment: Then why not simply load the symbols with `ld *`? What's the benefit of loading them to a specific address?

Comment: I am trying to debug a dump file for a custom binary. on linux there is a command for loading symbols at a custom address: gdb add-symbol-file address.
Is there any equivalent in WinDBG?

Comment: Why are you looking for a command that you don't need. Try `ld *`

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at AddSyntheticSymbol and AddSyntheticModule Search woodmann or google addsym windbg extension for an example to use AddSyntheticSymbol i am on 4 inch cant type more

Comment: I have looked into what you have said. But it does not help me very much.
My situation is like this: i have a module that has some custom binary code sections in it. I have the pdb for each custom binary. I can not use the AddSyntheticModule because this function wants a module, not a piece of code.

Comment: i am not sure i understand  your custom situation  you commented earlier that you were working on dump files now you are saying you have a binary will you be able to expand what you are talking about  if you are talkin about a binary do you specifically mean any executable format in windows like exe , dll , sys  etc were they compiled with any windows based compiler that emits a pdb as far as i know all the compilers generate one single pdb for the whole module not n number of pdbs for each code section

Answer (score 0):

This question makes a lot of sense. For instance, when a WindProc call is attempted against an unloaded module.  To accomplish this, use the `.reload` command.

[.reload docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff564805(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: The .reload command, as I know, matches each module with one symbol file. The problem, in my case, is that i want to specify more symbol files for one module (in that module I have custom binary code sections in it). This is why I needed something like the gdb command shown.